# Issue with csv2rec and polyfit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing what I thought would be a simple regression on my data however something is wrong. I use csv2rec to read my data but then I print the regression parameters m and b I get nan nan.

In case you want to preview the csv file here is some of it:

```
"Oxide","ooh","oh",
"MoO",3.06,0.01,
"IrO",2.79,-0.23,
```

What I want is a regression on the two rows. `x = a.oh` and `y = a.ooh`

Here is the script I am using

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import polyfit

a = mlab.csv2rec('rutilecsv.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlabel('E_OH / eV', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('E_OOH / eV', fontsize=12)

(m, b) = polyfit(a.oh, a.ooh, 1)

print m, b

ax.plot(a.oh, a.ooh, 'go')

plt.axis([-2, 3, 1, 6])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible that csv2rec is not interpreting your first row as column names and hence not converting the other numerical values?

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce this.  With your example data file I get `(m,b) = 1.125, 3.04875`, and a plot with two green circles.  [mpl 1.1.1rc.]  Are you sure that all the parts of the data you didn't list are okay, esp. at the end?  What do `any(numpy.isnan(a.ooh))` and `any(numpy.isnan(a.oh))` return?

Comment: If I had only runned the script after modifying the csv file for I would have caught. It did not matter in plot if you had empty elements but does in polyfit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just to put this to bed, this is exactly the symptom you'd get if there were missing data:

```
"Oxide","ooh","oh",
"MoO",3.06,0.01,
"IrO",2.79,-0.23,
"ZZ",2.79,,
```

results in

```
In [7]: a.ooh
Out[7]: array([ 3.06,  2.79,  2.79])

In [8]: a.oh
Out[8]: array([ 0.01, -0.23,   nan])

In [9]: polyfit(a.oh, a.ooh, 1)
Out[9]: array([ nan,  nan])
```

If you want to simply ignore the missing data, then you can simply pass `polyfit` only the points where both exist:

```
In [15]: good_data = ~(numpy.isnan(a.oh) | numpy.isnan(a.ooh))

In [16]: good_data
Out[16]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [17]: a.oh[good_data]
Out[17]: array([ 0.01, -0.23])

In [18]: a.ooh[good_data]
Out[18]: array([ 3.06,  2.79])

In [19]: polyfit(a.oh[good_data], a.ooh[good_data], 1)
Out[19]: array([ 1.125  ,  3.04875])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Are values converted propery
2. Try a['oh'] and a['ooh'] to access vectors

and maybe use option names to specify column names when reading file in.

Comment: DSM got it right. But thank you very much for trying to help.